# python watchdog module doesn't work with django/mod_wsgi under redhat server

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

We use django (1.7.5) with mod_wsgi under apache2 in redhat server, and try to use watchdog to monitor the files.

It works fine locally using `python manager.py runserver` command, while the event is not triggerred in wsgi mode when I deploy it into product environment

```
# wsgi.py
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()

LOGGER.debug("Starting to watch for config file changes.")
fw = FileWatcher()
```

```
# filewatcher
path = settings.PROJECT_ROOT
filename = 'config.json'
class ConfigHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory and event.src_path.endswith(filename):
            LOGGER.debug("The config has changed!, Reloading")

class FileWatcher(object):

    _instance = None
    _watching = False

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not cls._instance:
            LOGGER.debug("Creating new FileWatcher")
            cls._instance = super(FileWatcher, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

            cls.start_watching()

        return cls._instance

    @classmethod
    def start_watching(cls):
        if not cls._watching:
            LOGGER.debug("Starting to monitor the file: %s",
                        os.path.join(path, filename))
            event_handler = ConfigHandler()
            observer = Observer()
            observer.schedule(event_handler, path=path, recursive=False)
            observer.start()

            cls._watching = True
```

Comment: Could you share your code how you integrated watchdog into django project locally and with wsgi? From the above code, I can't get where your FileWatcher class initialised and works with views.py.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the route cause, the default Observer (`inotify.InotifyObserver`) doesn't work in old redhat server with old linux kernel

It is stated in http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#module-watchdog.observers

```
inotify.InotifyObserver Linux 2.6.13+   inotify(7) based observer
polling.PollingObserver Any fallback implementation
```

Therefore I changed it to generic one

```
    from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserver
    # http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html#module-watchdog.observers
    observer = PollingObserver()
```